# Using Oracle Developer Tools with Source Control for Visual Studio

Tags: oracle, version-control, tfs, odp.net

I'm a bit lost in implmementing/using tfs version control with Oracle products. The project I'm on is using visual studio 2012, tfs 2013, an oracle 11g server, a few copies of Oracle SQL Developer, and a few copies of toad.

I was recently looking for a way to do tfs version control through visual studio using oracle developer tools*. Is this a viable approach?
When tooling around with it, I've been able to create a database project with tables, procs, etc and put this under tfs version control. I've also been able to run these procs against my normal database server. However, I have not been able to put my existing database under version control. I have also not been able to run my code against the visual studio database project.

So can tfs be used with oracle developer tools to provide a version control solution?

Alternatively, are there any ways to integrate tfs version control with both Oracle SQL develoeper and toad?

---

*Oracle Developer Tools - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/visual-studio/overview/index-097110.html
On the oracle developer tools promo page it says

> "SQL Script Lifecycle with Source Control Integration: Generate SQL
>   scripts for Oracle schema objects that your .NET application uses,
>   manage them in an Oracle Database Project, check them into source
>   control, edit the scripts in the Oracle SQL Editor, and execute them
>   with a built in SQL*Plus execution engine."

How does this work? Can I automatically generate the scripts each night and check them in or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, after you install Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio, you can configure your Oracle Data Connections in the Server Explorer, create a new Oracle Database Project, then drag and drop packages or other items from the Server Explorer to your new project.  Then, after editing the .sql files that were generated, you can right-click on the .sql files generated and "Run" or "Run on...".  Finally, you can also run subsets of each script by right-clicking on a selection and choosing "Run selection".

You still need the discipline to ensure everyone edits packages via source control and not on the database directly.

Answer (score 2):

SSDT database projects in Visual Studio only support SQL Server.

One option is to try [Red Gate Source Control for Oracle](http://www.red-gate.com/products/oracle-development/source-control-for-oracle/), a tool developed by the company I work for. This supports both TFS and Subversion. I'd be interested to know if this is something that might work for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Toad to integrate Microsoft TFS changes. Please see : http://www.toadworld.com/products/toad-for-oracle/m/media-library/689.aspx